# bootstrap UI crashed on upgrading angular-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I upgraded angular-bootstrap version to v2.2.0 and all my UI functionality like dropdown, modals, accordions crashed. Along with angular-bootstrap, I also upgraded bootstrap-sass to v3.3.7 and jQuery to v3.1.1

I really don't understand that even with the latest versions of all dependency libraries, why isn't the Css functionality working. Do I need to add any other dependency too? I tried looking for solutions on the links below:

- https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
- https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

But i couldn't find any fix for it. I am adding just a part of uib-tabs code if that helps to track down the problem.

```
uib-tabset.tabs-flat(active="active")
    uib-tab(index="0", active="states['alert-details.overview']")
        tab-heading
            a.tab-head(ui-sref="alert-details.overview", translate)
                | Overview
    uib-tab(index="1", active="states['alert-details.history']")
        tab-heading
            a.tab-head(ui-sref="alert-details.history", translate)
                | History
    uib-tab(index="2", active="states['alert-details.trigger']")
        tab-heading
            a.tab-head(ui-sref="alert-details.trigger", translate)
                | Trigger Events
    uib-tab(index="3", active="states['alert-details.all-fields']")
        tab-heading
            a.tab-head(ui-sref="alert-details.all-fields", translate)
                | All Alert Fields
```

This is just for tabs. Other css components such as modals, accordions also doesn't work. So I am assuming it has to do with bootstrap CSS version. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: It would probably be useful to include sample code that can be used to reproduce the problem. Also, have you checked the browser error console (press F12)?

Comment: I don't see any console errors!